# How does Apache Curator try to reconnect when session expires?

Tags: java, apache, session, apache-curator, expired-sessions

I'm reading the documentation of [Apache Curator](http://curator.apache.org/errors.html), but I can't understand exactly what's the policy it tries to apply when the session expires.

Would it immediately set the connection to LOST, or would it retry to reconnect and re-establish all the watchers, and only after N failed attempts it would set the connection to LOST?

If it tries to re-establish, would it reset correctly ephemeral nodes and watches?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, in ZooKeeper session expiration (from the client point of view) doesn't occur until you've re-established connection to a healthy ensemble. i.e. you don't know your session has ended until you reconnect.

Apache Curator (note: I'm the main author) introduces a concept of "connection state" that is an abstraction on top of ZooKeeper's internal concept of state. Importantly, Curator's connection state handling has changed from versions prior to 3.x and versions 3.x and above.

Prior to 3.x, Curator's connection state had no relationship to the ZooKeeper session. Connection state LOST only meant that the configured RetryPolicy had given up. In Curator 3.x and above, when a connection to the ensemble is lost, Curator sets an internal timer and if that timer passes the negotiated session timeout before reconnecting to the ZooKeeper ensemble, Curator changes to LOST and "fakes" a session timeout to the internally managed ZooKeeper handle.

This is described here: http://curator.apache.org/errors.html

Comment: Thanks @Randgalt, I read the document but I was still confused.
So the versions 3.x and above do nothing to recover the connection after a session expired (watches/ephemeral nodes) and I have to handle those manually right?

Comment: If you are writing to the raw APIs, yes you have to recover your watches (there's no way not to). However, if you use any pre-built Curator recipe, this is all handled for you. Which is why I always say: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN6